# How to hide text when plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
firsts = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=12, freq='M') 
n_days =  list(firsts.days_in_month)  
n_days = [0] + n_days[:-1]
ticks = np.cumsum(n_days)  
ticks_dates = full_dates[ticks]
ticklabels = [date.strftime('%m-%d') for date in ticks_dates]
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels, rotation=45)
```

After the last line when the chart is plotted, this is also shown:

```
[Text(0, 0, '01-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '02-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '03-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '04-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '05-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '06-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '07-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '08-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '09-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '10-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '11-01'),
 Text(0, 0, '12-01')]
```

Is there anyway i can hide this? and have the chart only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a semicolon `;` after the last line to suppress the output

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels, rotation=45);
```